# Using MSBuild from Visual Studio 2017 in Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild

I am using Jenkins version 2.107.2. I also use Visual Studio 2017 Professional. Jenkins is connected to my BitBucket repo. But for Jenkins it is not possible to run my build successfully. I do always get this error:

```
error MSB4041: The MSBuild XML namespace must be the default XML namespace of the project. If the project was created in MSBuild 2003 format, add xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project was created in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.
```

Jenkins is running on my local machine.
The build in VS2017 runs perfectly. Without any problems. But in Jenkins the build fails.

I do use .NET Framework 4.7.1 with the programming language VB.NET and C#.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I don't know Jenkins, but that sounds like it's using a MSBuild that doesn't understand Roslyn (assuming you are attempting to build a Roslyn project). I'd think you need to provide more details for us to help you

Comment: There are several msbuild.exe files on my local machine. The only one that works is in this path: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"

The other one is here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

But the second one do not work well for me. I guess the second one should work but when i try to use the second one jenkins is not able to find the MSBuild.exe file :-(

Comment: Sounds like a possible permission issue where the Jenkins servcie accoutn can't read from the msbuild installation folder. To compile projects that rely on 2017 features you need to call the one in the 2017 folder.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to fix that issue?